# Export file from zabbix(v4.2) and import it into zabbix(v4.0) failed

Tags: version, zabbix

Today, I wanted to export a template from zabbix(v4.2) to zabbix(v4.0), but after I exported it from zabbix(v4.2) and I am going to import it in zabbix(v4.0), it tells me like this:

> Invalid tag "/zabbix_export/version": unsupported version number.

I thought it would be a version problem, and I changed the version no. from 4.2 to 4.0, and I did the import once more, it still tells me:

> Invalid tag "/zabbix_export/templates/template(1)": unexpected tag "tags".

I then read the official document, it tolds me:

> Older versions are not supported.
>   Long term support is provided only for the version called LTS.

Any solutions for this？

Answer (score 0):

The important bit is in the [compatibility page](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/compatibility). Namely, only import from previous versions is supported. Importing from a more recent version into an older one is not supported.

You can manually edit the XML to conform to the 4.0 format (possibly losing some content like template tags), but there is no documentation on details, or how complicated it might be.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, I've solved this problem by upgrading the version, from 4.0->4.2.
After upgrading, every weird problems are solved.